# Datatable not cleared usage

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am creating a simple report in PHP and AJAX displayed on Datatable.
The user shall be able to select the *from date* and *to date*, then data will be display according to the selected dates.

My problem is if I select no sales dates, the data are not cleared and still show the previous records, I don't understand why.

I attached the screenshot of the form below

[image: screenshot of the form]

I tried to achieve this with the code below

```js
function get_all()
{
    var total=0;
    var amount=0;
    var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
    var to_date = $('#to_date').val();
    $('#tbl-projects').dataTable().fnDestroy();
    

    $.ajax({
        url:"all_sales.php",

        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},
      
        success: function (data) 
        {
            $('#tbl-projects').dataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    , 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                ],
                "aaData": data
                ,
                "scrollX": true,
                "aoColumns": [
                    {"sTitle": "Member No", "mData": "mno"},
                    {"sTitle": "Member Name", "mData": "pname"},
                    {"sTitle": "Amount", "mData": "amount"},
                    {"sTitle": "Month", "mData": "months"},
                    {"sTitle": "Payment Date", "mData": "paydate"},
                ]
            });
            data.forEach(function(recordInLoop) 
            {
                amount += Number(recordInLoop.amount);
            });
            $('#amount').val(amount);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log('Request Status: ' + xhr.status  );
            console.log('Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText );
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            var text = $($.parseHTML(xhr.responseText)).filter('.trace-message').text();
            console.log(text)
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You can reset the date field After the success response.

Comment: how to reset  .................

Comment: Check the below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function get_all()
     {
        var total=0;
        var amount=0;
        var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
        var to_date = $('#to_date').val();
        $('#tbl-projects').dataTable().fnDestroy();
        

        $.ajax({
            url:"all_sales.php",

            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},
          
            success: function (data) 
            {
                $('#tbl-projects').dataTable({
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                        , 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                    ],
                    "aaData": data
                    ,
                    "scrollX": true,
                    "aoColumns": [
                        {"sTitle": "Member No", "mData": "mno"},
                        {"sTitle": "Member Name", "mData": "pname"},
                        {"sTitle": "Amount", "mData": "amount"},
                        {"sTitle": "Month", "mData": "months"},
                        {"sTitle": "Payment Date", "mData": "paydate"},
                    ]
                });
                data.forEach(function(recordInLoop) 
                {
                    amount += Number(recordInLoop.amount);
                });
                $('#amount').val(amount);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                console.log('Request Status: ' + xhr.status  );
                console.log('Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText );
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                var text = $($.parseHTML(xhr.responseText)).filter('.trace-message').text();
                // Reset text box  
                $('#from_date').val('');
                $('#to_date').val('');

                console.log(text)
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

OR

```
 $('#from_date').datepicker('setDate', null);
 $('#to_date').datepicker('setDate', null);
```